# Using swagger-codegen to create templates for new classes

Tags: swagger, mustache, swagger-codegen

I'm trying to use swagger to create a templates for classes so that when someone wants to write a new class into my project, he will just need to write a json file and activate the swagger codegen.

I created a sample mustache file and a json, and the template is created and written by swagger, BUT, instead of inserting the parameter I want it leaves a blank space.
The example below will probably explain better.... (I am trying to create a template for python right now):

**The mustache file:**

```
class {{classname}}:

def __init__(self, value):
    self._value = value

def print_line(self):
    if self._value > 10:
        print "val bigger than 10"
    else:
        print "zero"
```

**The json file:**

```
{
"swagger": "2.0",
"info": {
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Trying to create a template class"
    },
"paths": {},
"classname": "Template_Class_Example"
```

}

**The Result:**

```
class :

def __init__(self, value):
    self._value = value

def print_line(self):
    if self._value > 10:
        print "val bigger than 10"
    else:
        print "zero"
```

As you can see, 'classname' wasn't replaced, but left blank.

Am I missing something?
Is it even possible to do what I want using swagger-codegen?

Thank you in advance,

Jacob

Comment: Have you checked if that's a valid spec? Which language are you using in the generation or is it a custom generator?

Comment: I'm using the given swagger codegen, trying to create a class in python using the files I wrote in my question. If it helps, this is the command I use java -jar swagger-codegen-cli.jar -l python -i /path/to/Json -t /path/to/folder/with/mustache